# Update using react chartjs-2 npm makes y axis labels change.is it possible to make constant?

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs-2

Iam using reactchartjs-2 npm. Iam updating line chart in each 10 second.When update happens y axis points(label) is changing.I need to make that label constant .is it possible?.

```
const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Temperature',
        data: [],
        fill: false,
        borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
        tension: 0.1,
      },
    ],
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    let dataIndex = 0 // Index to track the current position in orgData

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      // Get the current data point
      const currentData = orgData[dataIndex]

      // Update the chart data
      setChartData((prevChartData) => {
        const nextChartData = {
          labels: [...prevChartData.labels, currentData?.Time || ''],
          datasets: [
            {
              ...prevChartData.datasets[0],
              data: [...prevChartData.datasets[0].data, currentData?.Temperature || 0],
            },
          ],
        }

        // Keep only the last MAX_DATA_POINTS data points
        nextChartData.labels = nextChartData.labels.slice(-MAX_DATA_POINTS)
        nextChartData.datasets[0].data = nextChartData.datasets[0].data.slice(-MAX_DATA_POINTS)

        return nextChartData
      })

      // Move to the next data point or start from the first if at the end
      dataIndex = (dataIndex + 1) % orgData.length
    }, 10000)

    // Clear the interval on component unmount
    return () => clear Interval(interval)
  }, [orgData])
```

I tried this code but still it is not working